# Fix Error The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

The following code works fine

```
    Dim testRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim testResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Try
        testRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/checksomething.aspx", "http://168.108.220.108/"))
        With testRequest
            .Timeout = 30000
            .Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        End With
        testResponse = testRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(testResponse.GetResponseStream)
        Dim str As String = sr.ReadToEnd

    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim s = ex.InnerException
    Finally
    End Try
```

this one returns error message (ex.InnerException returns The target principal name is incorrect)

```
    Dim testRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim testResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
    Try
        testRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/checksomething.aspx", "http://ServerName.domainName.something.something"))
        With testRequest
            .Timeout = 30000
            .Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        End With
        testResponse = testRequest.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(testResponse.GetResponseStream)
        Dim str As String = sr.ReadToEnd

    Catch ex As WebException
        Dim s = ex.InnerException
    Finally
    End Try
```

So the only difference between 2 is link
"http://168.108.220.108/"
"http://ServerName.domainName.something.something"

I can access this link through internet explorer: http://ServerName.domainName.something.something

Is it something that needs to be corrected on IIS?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/288167/error-message-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-when-manually-replica

Comment: The link above suggests to make changes on DC - which I am not allowed.  I contacted administrator and he suggested to play with IIS settings.....